# How to use react-select with react-bootstrap to get the values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, react-bootstrap, react-select

I'm developing an App in ReactJS and I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import Select from "react-select";

const App = () => {

    const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);

    const [select, setSelect] = useState({
        name: "",
        category: ""
    });

    const handleChange = e => {
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        setSelect(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        [name]: value
        }));
    };

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    ...
    /* get data */
    ...

    const categories = data.map((item) => ({ value: item.id, label: item.Name }));

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <Form noValidate validated={validated}>
                <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} md="4" controlId="validationCustom01">
                        <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            required
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Name"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Check!</Form.Control.Feedback>
                        <Form.Control.Feedback>Ok!</Form.Control.Feedback>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} md="4" controlId="validationCustom02">
                        <Form.Label>Category</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            required
                            name="category"
                            as="select"
                            placeholder="Category"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        >
                        <Select
                                options={categories}
                                defaultValue={true}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                name="category"
                                id="search-select"
                            />
                        </Form.Control>
                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Check!</Form.Control.Feedback>
                        <Form.Control.Feedback>Ok!</Form.Control.Feedback>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}
        
export default App;
```

And I want to be able to use `react-select` together with `react-bootstrap` as shown above.
I need the `Select` component to adapt to the code so that I can use the `react-bootstrap` validation and have all the data selected/entered to be able to insert it, I need to pass those as follows, as an example:

```
console.log(select);

{name: "", category: ""}
name: "Name"
category: "Category"
__proto__: Object
```

How can I do it? I need it because otherwise I have to use

```
<Form.Control
    required
    name="category"
    as="select"
    placeholder="Category"
    onChange={handleChange}
>
<option hidden value="" selected>Select</option>
    {
        categories.map(elem => {
            return <option  ... >Name</option>
        })
    }
</Form.Control>
```

and the select remains without style.

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish to be honest. Would be cool if you could put your code into a Sandbox and then point to specific behavior you want to add/fix.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i did it there: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-fast-jz5ng?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what I need is the Select to be compatible with the `Form.Control` for it to render and to be able to get the selected data in the same object.

Comment: The sandbox is currently broken. Is that something you can't fix or you meant to fix it?

Comment: is something that I fixed with:             `<Form.Control
              required
              name="category"
              as="select"
              placeholder="Category"
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              <option hidden value="" selected>
                Select
              </option>
              {categories.map((elem) => {
                return <option>Name</option>;
              })}
            </Form.Control>`

Comment: I add an image in the question. what I want is to be able to use the `Select` component for the functions it trea and the like.

Comment: you can see the correction in sandbox, but I want to use the `Selec`t component of `react-select`

Comment: I want to use the `Select` component and use the `react-bootstrap` validation and get the `values` in the same object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you simply want to use react-select in your app. This should be pretty straightforward. I have created a dedicated element for you that uses react-select:

```
const SelectBox = ({ options }) => {
  const [optionSelected, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (selected) => {
    setSelectedOptions(selected);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      options={options}
      isLoading={!options}
      closeMenuOnSelect={true}
      onChange={handleChange}
      value={optionSelected}
      name={"your_select_name"}
    />
  );
};
```

You can just render it like so:

```
...
<SelectBox options={categories} />
...
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-torvalds-kzcug?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks! this way is the way !! we just have to solve that the `handleChange = e => {...};` take the value of the `Select`. Suggestions?

Comment: @bonnegnu Sure. Check out the sandbox link, I have updated it.

Comment: I need you to show it like this `{name: "Name", category: "A"}` Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @bonnegnu Try now

Comment: you're very close to getting it! what we have to bring are the value: {name: "value input Name", category: "value select select1"} Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: That's what it already does. `select1` is the input name. You can change it to anything you want.